# Blocking in user-level thread

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I have some confusion regarding user-level thread blocking. As we know that one user-level thread blocking leads to the whole process being blocked, then why is "responsiveness" one of the benefit of multi-threading? Given in the book of Silberschatz "Operating System Concepts":

> Multithreading in interactive application may allow a program to
>   continue running even if part of it is blocked or is performing a
>   lengthy operation, thereby increasing responsiveness to the user.

Is this referring to kernel-level threads only or is there something i am not able to understand?

So, the question is, how can responsiveness be an advantage of threads, when one user-level thread blocking results in entire process being blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, the question is, how can responsiveness be an advantage of threads, when one user-level thread blocking results in entire process being blocked?

User-level threads only block under two circumstances:

1. When they hit a page fault or some other condition that the threading library can't handle.
2. When the entire process has no way to make forward progress.

This is the primary job that a user-level threading implementation has -- to take functions that would normally block and replace them with non-blocking versions so that other user-level threads can make forward progress.

That still means that if any user-level thread hits a page fault, the entire process cannot make forward progress until the page fault is serviced.

Answer (score 1):

With user-level threading, the actual threads NEVER block -- any operation that might block is instead intercepted and the non-blocking equivalent done instead.  If the user level thread DID block, as you note, it would inadvertantly block other threads, which is broken.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some confusion regarding user-level thread blocking. As we know that one user-level thread blocking leads to the whole process being blocked, then why is "responsiveness" one of the benefit of multi-threading?

That is only true on some operating systems.

> So, the question is, how can responsiveness be an advantage of threads, when one user-level thread blocking results in entire process being blocked?

The systems widely in use when "user threads" were developed  often had software interrupts that prevented the entire thread from being blocked.

Now, any operating system worth its salt has real threads and "user threads" are a relic of the ages and operating systems that have not kept up.